# How can I make Debian 12 automatically turn the laptop screen back on upon opening the lid?

Tags: linux, laptop, debian

I've installed Debian 12 on my old laptop with the intention of using it as a home server, **avoiding the installation of any graphical interface**. However, I've encountered an issue where the screen turns off upon closing the lid and fails to turn back on upon reopening.

Initially, I attempted to address this by configuring `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in the `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` file. Although successful in preventing the laptop from entering sleep mode, the screen persisted in turning off and remained unresponsive upon lid reopening.

Exploring an alternative solution, I adjusted `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi=off"` in the `/etc/default/grub` file. While this approach seemed effective, it introduced numerous boot errors and appeared to disable essential services and network interfaces.

In subsequent attempts, I experimented with different changes individually:

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet button.lid_init_state=open"`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet acpi=linux"`

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nomodeset"`

However, none of these adjustments seemed to have any impact on the issue.

Additionally, I tried resolving the problem using the command `setterm -blank 0`, but this, too, proved ineffective.

**It's noteworthy that the screen remains continuously on when I refrain from closing the laptop lid.**

**UPDATE**:
As a temporary measure, I use the `vbetool dpms on` command over SSH to turn on the laptop screen when needed.

Comment: This might have something to do with the gpu/drm kernel driver. On at least some laptop, screen turning off caused by lid closing would make the screen deemed / effectively disconnected. If there's some bug related to hot plug detection or so, the display might not be able to come back even when the screen is connected again. (Does it occur only with lid closing? I mean like if you make the laptop sleep with a command or some keyboard button, and keep the lid open, does the problem occur as well?)

Comment: When I comment `HandleLidSwitch=ignore` in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, the result is that when I close the lid, the laptop enters sleep mode. However, upon reopening the lid, the laptop wakes up, and the screen turns on. The issue is that I don't want the laptop to go to sleep when I close the lid, which is why I made that modification in the logind.conf file.

Comment: I previously operated Ubuntu 16.04 server, with the same modifications to the /etc/systemd/logind.conf file, and the laptop exhibited proper behavior—no sleep mode, and it also woke up upon opening the lid.

Comment: If you reproduce the problem, and then trigger machine sleep manually (via a keyboard button if any; or prepare in advance a terminal with the command typed) and wake it up, does the display come back?

Comment: Yes, Running `vbetool dpms on` command when the screen is off appeared to reawaken the display.

Comment: Hmm, that sounds strange. Does the display come back when you e.g. press any key / move your mouse in the following scenario respectively: 1. lid closed and re-opened 2. set dpms to off with `vbetool`.

Comment: In both scenarios, the screen remains inactive.

Comment: Hmm never mind. Apparently vbetool dpms off is not quite the same as xset dpms force off. My bet is then still the that the problem resides in the gpu/drm kernel driver then. Probably not much you can do other than filing a bug report...